# jdbc Driver exception for mySQL in jdeveloper

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a ADF application using MySQL for DB. When i try to run my JSF page i am getting below error. I have added the jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin to my project but still i am getting this error.

<3 Mar, 2015 10:12:22 PM IST>    (ConnectionEnvFactory.java:131)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.initPooledResourceFactory(ConnectionPool.java:712)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:235)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> <3 Mar, 2015 10:12:22 PM IST>     
>   <3 Mar, 2015 10:12:22 PM IST>    (ConnectionEnvFactory.java:131)
>       at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.initPooledResourceFactory(ConnectionPool.java:712)
>       at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:235)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> [10:12:22 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
>   [10:12:22 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)

I am really stuck with this.Please help me out..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: <3 Mar, 2015 10:12:22 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1425400941647' for task '3'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: '
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
 at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:302)
Caused By: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.parseException(JDBCUtil.java:301)

Comment: this is the error guys..Sorry i didn't add to the message..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should [use the edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28837314/edit) to add the error message into the question.  Even if it's solved, you should do this to help searching etc for anyone with the same error message in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Have to place the lib file in Domain directory of the weblogic server and also add to the project properties

Project Properties -> Libraries and Classpath -> Add

Make sure exported..